# Return a discriminating union from object key

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to return a discriminated union given an objects key:

```js
type Foo = {
    key: 'foo';
    value: number;
};

type Bar = {
    key: 'bar';
    value: string;
};

type Obj = {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
};

function getField(obj: Obj, key: keyof Obj): Foo | Bar {
    // Error here:
    // Type '{ key: keyof Obj; value: string | number; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo | Bar'.
    return { key, value: obj[key] };
}
```

When I try the above code I get the error: `Type '{ key: keyof Obj; value: string | number; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo | Bar'.`

I think I need to link the type of `obj[key]` to the type of `key` somehow but I'm not sure how to accomplish this without casting.

Comment: You're running into a situation with what I call *correlated unions*, as discussed in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The fix as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) is to refactor so to use a generic function and a mapping interface, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3yekw).  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining it.  If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it is true that the return value of `getField()` will definitely be either a `Foo` or a `Bar`, the compiler cannot see it.  The `key` parameter is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"foo" | "bar"`, and therefore `obj[key]` is also of a union type, `number | string`.  These types are the correct types.  But the types of `key` and `obj[key]` do not contain sufficient information to recognize that `{ key, value: obj[key] }` will be assignable to type `Foo | Bar`.

If I hand you a value `k` of type `"foo" | "bar"` and a value `v` of type `number | string`, you'd have no reason to believe that `{ key: k, value: v }` would be a valid `Foo` or a `Bar`.  It's quite possible that `k` is `"foo"` while `v` is some string.

Now, *we* happen to know that `key` and `obj[key]` are *correlated* in a way that's not captured by looking at their types separately.  If `key` is `"foo"` then `obj[key]` is `number`, and if `key` is `"bar"`, then `obj[key]` is `string`.  But unfortunately the compiler only sees the separate types, the same as the `k` and `v` example from before.

It would be nice if you could tell the compiler to consider the `"foo"` situation separately from the `"bar"` situation, but that just can't happen in a single line of code with expressions of union types.

This issue with correlated union types is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

---

TypeScript 4.6 introduced [some improvements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#indexed-access-inference-improvements) in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to address this issue.

The general approach is refactor to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function, so that the single line of code can be evaluated for just `"foo"` or just `"bar"`.  That is, we make it generic in `K extends keyof Obj`.  And we must also refactor the types so that the compiler can see `Foo` and `Bar` being some generic function of `K`.

Here is the refactoring necessary:

```
type FooBar<K extends keyof Obj> = { [P in K]: { key: P, value: Obj[P] } }[K];
type Foo = FooBar<"foo">;
type Bar = FooBar<"bar">;
```

The `FooBar<K>` type is a *distributive object type* as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109.  The type `FooBar<"foo">` is the same as your original `Foo`, and `FooBar<"bar">` is the same as `Bar`.  And `FooBar<keyof Obj>` is the same as `Foo | Bar`.

Now you can write `getField()` like this:

```
function getField<K extends keyof Obj>(obj: Obj, key: K): FooBar<K> {
  return { key, value: obj[key] }; // okay
}
```

And verify that it works as desired:

```
const obj: Obj = { foo: 1, bar: "x" };
const f: Foo = getField(obj, "foo");
const b: Bar = getField(obj, "bar");
```

Hooray!

---

Note well: it is important that `FooBar` is written in terms of a generic `{key: P, value: Obj[P]}` and that `getField()` is implemented with the analogous `{key: key, value: obj[key]}`.  If you rewrite `FooBar` to be unrelated to the `Obj` type, such as, for example,

```
type FooBar<K extends keyof Obj> = Extract<Foo | Bar, { key: K }>;
```

then you would get the same error again:

```
function getField<K extends keyof Obj>(obj: Obj, key: K): FooBar<K> {
  return { key, value: obj[key] }; // error!
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB1A9gJwNZSQbwCgkkAXATxmQHkAjAKyQF58jikAzNNALiWAFcwNCBgDcrYjRAZeUEhgCWwAObjiAX3GtylJADEuAIWkAeANJIIADxIRgAE1xYIZNOyS06APib4kAbQAFJCUkMwBdXjwkZzJeQIAaJAA3EAAbfgheTyDwpHV8-wi1UgpkAzRfCuMMEwAiTjQ6rxKdZBqqo1M6qQxmrVZ2fmB4EgU0YCRlCBI9BQg0+3NLGztHGJc3D3ovAAo0emz6JNjeMwBKXmrTMx9CNiQMGf4MSejYpNSMrKQDun9YnlNKx1ARWPAJnJfodtgxmNFGrwAIxJXq8OpWOr5EoQ4BQ9hXLi+aazeaLfbHJANLh1c44yEkJA0XgdZgkuYLewUuhJHrSWniUEEUCQWAIdoYNDON7aMqw3z3NiIviCYRiCRM6SyeRKVQgkqy3QVBUa05Uxp1ErEL6ZXgCIQiEqg4htJCslgPM18vpWlLpW1IOSKFROsEuuXXWoWay2BxOTbuTw+ZgAURsGAQJBMxoAPm7pEl3i4zvkWmGOMNRuNJuyyUto6s4xtXImdtyjjzm2dLvoulG7hqniQXm9m59-T8-gCXEDREgAPTzywYSUYACEIPLuKhfw7Co4XGRqK1VMx2PBDI4hMqbJmHPJf15FrpF7xjOZ+YwxLvde5vN6AoEOoQA)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
type Foo = {
    key: 'foo';
    value: number;
};

type Bar = {
    key: 'bar';
    value: string;
};

type Obj = {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
};

function getField(obj: Record<'foo' | 'bar', any>, key: 'foo' | 'bar'): Foo | Bar {
    return { key, value: obj[key] };
}
```

Comment: This leads to the unfortunate situation where `getField()` allows an invalid `Obj` as input.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJq2Dm).  Can you explain what your goal is here?  If the goal is just that the error goes away, then you should probably be very explicit about the potential consequences of suppressing a type error via `any`.